# How can i set title to powerbi embedded report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a powerbi embedded report and I want to set title attribute to make my report accessible easily. Is there any way i can do that?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or additional details on where you're trying to set the title

Answer (score 1):

You can use the title attribute to add text to the element it belongs to. If someone is using a screen reader, it will read the additional information about the element for the person. In order to set the title attribute of the embed component, use setComponentTitle.

```
let component = powerbi.embed(…);
component.setComponentTitle(“Analytics report”)
```

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/accessibility